# Edit the markup of categories list

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes

I want to list x number of categories. I'm using `wp_list_categories` function, it generates the following markup

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
```

However I need to wrap every two li items inside a div, For example:

```
<div class="one">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
</div>
```

How I can do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### List of possibilities

You got exactly two options to alter the output of [`wp_list_categories()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_list_categories/)

1. Use a filter after the MarkUp was generated and re-format it:

   ```
   add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'wpse88292_reformat_list_cats', 10, 2 );
   function wpse88292_reformat_list_cats( $output, $args )
   {
       // Reformat `$output` here
       // You can use `$args` to only this when condition X == Y

       return $output;
   }
   ```
2. Use a custom walker

   ```
   class Walker_Reformated_Category extends Walker_Category
   {
       static $counter = 0;

       function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args )
       {
           if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
               return;

           // Count up before doing anything
           self::$counter++;

           // Do additional formatting of `$output`in here
           // It's passed by reference(!)

           if ( 0 === self::$counter %2 )
               $output = "<div class='class-{$counter}'>{$output}";
       }

       function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args )
       {
           if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
               return;

           // Do additional formatting of `$output`in here
           // It's passed by reference(!)

           // Don't count at the end of the el!
           if ( 0 === self::$counter %2 )
               $output = "{$output}</div>";
       }
   }

   # Call the categories list with your walker
   wp_list_categories( array(
       // ... some args
       'walker' => new Walker_Reformated_Category()
       // ... even more args
   ) );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `echo=0` parameter to take it into a string variable:

```
$items=wp_list_categories("echo=0&title_li=");
```

then you can explode it to get the array:

```
$items=str_replace("</li>","</li>|",$items);
$items=explode("|",$items);
```

Then you can loop through the items:

```
foreach($items as $i=>$item){
   // to stuff
}
```

You can consider something like this for your div wrap:

```
echo "<div>";
foreach($items as $i=>$item){
    echo $item;
    if($i%2==1){echo "</div><div>";}    
}
echo "</div>";
```